# In R, how can I loop over data frames?

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm working with several data frames with names following this structure:

```
data.bzk.18
data.bzk.19
data.bzk.20
data.bzk.21
```

I'd like to use `plyr` to summarize data and basically run the following on each of the data frames:

```
bzk.tot.18 <- plyr::count(data.bzk.18, c("BZNR"))
```

I wanted to put loop over all of them and came up with solution like that

```
for(i in 18:21) {
  to <- paste("bzk.tot", i, sep = ".")
  assign(to, i)

  from <- paste("data.bzk", i, sep = ".")
  assign(from, i)

  to <- plyr::count(from, c("BZNR")) #totals
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Where have I done mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the short answer is that instead of:

```
   to <- plyr::count(from, c("BZNR")) #totals
```

use:

```
    assign(to, plyr::count(get(from), c("BZNR")) )
```

and get rid of the previous `assign` statements.

---

the long answer is that you probably do not want to go about it such a fashion.   Better to collect all of your data.frames into a list and iterate over the list instead.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it didn't work. I get an error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'BZNR' not found`

Comment: @radek, sorry about that.  `from` needs to be wrapped in `get(.)`.  The answer has been updated.

Comment: Yhanks - that did the job!